# Python Script: Run two different commands that depend on 3D View update

Tags: python, scripting

I'm developing an addon that need to capture the position of the same object in one and other frame. Actually I had to create four buttons for it, one to put on start frame, other to end frame, other to capture start frame positions and other to capture end frame positions. I tryied to do it in one command:

```
import bpy

frame1 = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_start
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame1

bpy.ops.object.capture_object_start_position()


frame2 = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame2

bpy.ops.object.capture_object_end_position()
```

I tryied to put the commands update() and redraw() but it doesnt works, I read in some places that the problem is in the way of Blender works with the bpy.ops.* commands.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `frame_set`

```
import bpy

def obj_pos(obj, frame):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
    print("frame:", frame)
    print("object location:", obj.location)

me = bpy.context.active_object
frame1 = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_start

obj_pos(me, frame1)

frame2 = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end

obj_pos(me, frame2)
```

Comment: `obj.matrix_world.translation` will give global location, taking into account hierarchy,  constraints, physics etc.

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly! I change a little the code and run! http://www.ciceromoraes.com.br/screenshots/GENERATE.png Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly! I change a little the code and run!